# Convert the JavaScript Object to similar items

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, typescript

I have a JavaScript array of objects which looks like this,

```
var object = [{"Fruit" : "Banana", "NAPrice" : 45},
     {"Fruit" : "Banana", "EUPrice" : 50},
     {"Fruit" : "Banana", "AUPrice" : 30},
     {"Fruit" : "Apple" , "NAPrice" : 25},
     {"Fruit" : "Apple" , "EUPrice" : 20},
     {"Fruit" : "Apple" , "AUPrice" : 23},
     {"Fruit" : "Berry", "NAPrice" : 18},
     {"Fruit" : "Berry", "EUPrice" : 8},
     {"Fruit" : "Berry", "AUPrice" : 17}];
```

As you can see in each object there are similar fruits but different traits, can we combine them altogether? To look something like this,

```
var object = [{"Fruit" : "Banana", "NAPrice" : 45, "EUPrice" : 50, "AUPrice" : 30},
     {"Fruit" : "Apple", "NAPrice" : 25, "EUPrice" : 20, "AUPrice": 23}
     {"Fruit" : "Berry", "NAPrice" : 18, "EUPrice" : 8, "AUPrice": 18}];
```

PS: Note that there will be common number of prices for fruits, here 3 fruits prices of each kind.

Comment: The objects have duplicate keys in the expected output.

Comment: @adiga, modified the question. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @SharathKamlekar Does the added answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to achieve this. I first created an Object with keys as fruit values and kept assigning Objects to it. Later I took out all the values of the Object.

```js
var object = [{"Fruit" : "Banana", "NAPrice" : 45},
     {"Fruit" : "Banana", "EUPrice" : 50},
     {"Fruit" : "Banana", "AUPrice" : 30},
     {"Fruit" : "Apple" , "NAPrice" : 25},
     {"Fruit" : "Apple" , "EUPrice" : 20},
     {"Fruit" : "Apple" , "AUPrice" : 23},
     {"Fruit" : "Berry", "NAPrice" : 18},
     {"Fruit" : "Berry", "EUPrice" : 8},
     {"Fruit" : "Berry", "AUPrice" : 17}];
     
     
var newObj = object.reduce((acc, ob) => {
  if (acc[ob.Fruit]) {
    Object.assign(acc[ob.Fruit], {...ob});
  } else {
    acc[ob.Fruit] = {...ob};
  }
  return acc
}, {});

var merges = Object.values(newObj)

console.log(merges)
```